# Echoing a mix of PHP and HTML with escaping not working

Tags: php

This is all a part of function, however it's not working for some reason.

```
function _bot_detected() {

  if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) && preg_match('/bot|crawl|slurp|spider/i', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {
    echo '';
  }
  else {
    echo '<div class=/"video-wrap/">
            <video id=/"slide-video/" poster=/"images/videos/' .$rand. '.jpg/" preload=/"auto/" loop muted autoplay>
            <source src=/"images/videos/' .$rand. '.webm/" type=/"video/webm/" />
            <source src=/"images/videos/' .$rand. '.mp4/" type=/"video/mp4/" />
            </video>
            <div class=/"video-overlay/" style=/"background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);/"></div>
            </div>
            <a href=/"#/" data-scrollto=/"#section-M9/" data-easing=/"easeInOutExpo/" data-speed=/"1250/" data-offset=/"65/" class=/"one-page-arrow dark/"><i class=/"icon-angle-down infinite animated fadeInDown/"></i></a>
            </div>';

;
  }
```

I escaped html by changing `"` to `/"` but it did not work. The error I'm getting is:

```
[15-Aug-2015 23:34:44 Europe/Paris] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'video' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in E:\wamp\www\assets\x\video.php on line 8
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using without escaping

```
    function _bot_detected() {
     if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) && preg_match('/bot|crawl|slurp|spider/i', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {
     echo '';
     }
     else {
        echo '<div class="video-wrap">
        <video id="slide-video" poster="images/videos/' .$rand. '.jpg" preload="auto" loop muted autoplay>
        <source src="images/videos/' .$rand. '.webm" type="video/webm" />
        <source src="images/videos/' .$rand. '.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        </video>
        <div class="video-overlay" style="background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);"></div>
        </div>
        <a href="#" data-scrollto="#section-M9" data-easing="easeInOutExpo" data-speed="1250" data-offset="65" class="one-page-arrow dark">
        <i class="icon-angle-down infinite animated fadeInDown"></i></a>
        </div>';
         }

     }
```

Comment: Worked out great. Thanks !